# SignalR: can a property setter on a hub be called by a client?

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Having defined a simple SignalR Hub:

```
public class TheHub : Hub {

    public void CsharpMethod(string smth) {...}

    public string CsharpProperty { get; set; }
}
```

...then it's easy, from a javascript client, to call a hub's method:

```
$.connection.theHub.server.csharpMethod("parameter");
```

But is there any support for (directly) calling the hub's getter or setter of a property (like `CsharpProperty` in the example)?

Comment: Nope, but why would you? The hub lifetime is transient so the reference will die after the call.

Comment: Lazyness. I have a (not transient) model that exposes an interface, and it would been simpler (using Resharper) to implement the same interface on the hub and delegate all calls to my model. Oh well :)